# how to set ids for many to many entity framework model

Tags: c#, entity-framework

this is how my model looks at the moment:

it works but I would like to know if it's possible to also add ids property, that will be filled with the ids of the corresponding virtual (lazy) property, and changing it would affect the Db/model, as expected.

```
public class Meal
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Dinner> Dinners { get; set; }
   // add ICollection<int> DinnersIds { get;set; }
}
public class Dinner
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
   // add ICollection<int> MealsIds { get;set; }
}
```

my dbcontext:

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
     ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Dinner>().HasMany(r => r.Meals).WithMany(o => o.Dinners).Map(f =>
        {
            f.MapLeftKey("DinnerId");
            f.MapRightKey("MealId");
        });

    ...

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess the answer is no, the behavior is very complex, but I'm interested to see if it is possible. The bigger question I have is: Why do you want this?

Comment: @Vlad274 this would help me optimize some code, also I think there would be a bit less db usage, because there's no need to query the right side of the ManyToMany